# Firebase Database Structure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application about restaurant.
But having some trouble with the Firebase database structure.
The database structure of my code is like this:

```
restaurants {
             AutoID {
                      name: "nnnnn",
                      phone:"88888888" }
             AutoID {
                      name: "nnnnn",
                      phone:"88888888" }
             image {
                    AutoID: URL
                    AutoID: URL }
}
```

How can I change the structure to become like this:

```
restaurants {
             AutoID {
                      name: "nnnnn",
                      phone:"88888888",
                      image: URL }
             AutoID {
                      name: "nnnnn",
                      phone:"88888888",
                      image: URL }
```

The current code are:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    addRestaurant()
}

func addRestaurant()
{
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants")

    let key = ref?.childByAutoId().key

    let name = addName.text

    let phone = addPhone.text

    ref?.child(key!).setValue(["name": name, "phone": phone])

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    addImage.image = image

    var data = Data()
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

    let uniqueName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("restaurantImage").child("\(uniqueName)")
    imageRef.put(data, metadata: nil).observe(.success){(snapshot) in
        let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        let imageDBRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants/image")
        let key = imageDBRef.childByAutoId().key
        imageDBRef.child(key).setValue(downloadURL)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Where you are showing imagepicker?

Comment: here: @IBAction func addImageFromLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(image, animated: true)
        {
            //later
        }
    }

Comment: When you are adding this URL at that time have you added name and phone in Firebase?

Comment: no. after picking the photo, the database and storage already have the URL. Actually I hope that name , phone and image can upload at the same time by clicking the save button.

Comment: So it means after you pick image save in the storage add entry of it in DB then you press the save button to store `name` and `phone` in DB right ?

Comment: Yes. This is what happened in present .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told that you are first Storing image in `FIRStorage` then adding `name` and `phone` what you need to do is inside the closure of `imageRef` you need to store the reference of your stored image URL, so declare one instance property in your controller and set it inside that closure and also don't set image url in DB that time, after that with save button use that newly created property to post name, phone and url at same time.

```
var imageURL = ""

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    addImage.image = image

    var data = Data()
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

    let uniqueName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("restaurantImage").child("\(uniqueName)")
    imageRef.put(data, metadata: nil).observe(.success){(snapshot) in
        self.imageURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        //Remove other code        
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now with your `addRestaurant` add key for `image` and set its value with `imageURL`

```
func addRestaurant()
{
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants")        
    let key = ref?.childByAutoId().key        
    let name = addName.text        
    let phone = addPhone.text        
    ref?.child(key!).setValue(["name": name, "phone": phone, "image": imageURL])

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and have a nice day ! ^^  Thank you !

Comment: @elizabeth Welcome mate :)

Comment: I got an extension question about retrieving image from the Firebase Database https://stackoverflow.com/q/44330769/8102507 Would you mind to have a look of it ? Thank you very much !