# Retrieve Image From Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

extension of [Firebase Database Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44327131/8102507)

After uploaded the image, name and phone to the Firebase Database and Firebase Storage.

I am having trouble with retrieving the image from the Firebase to the Table View.

This is the Table View Class :

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewHongKong: UITableView!

var restaurantList = [RestaurantModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants")

    ref?.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0
        {
            self.restaurantList.removeAll()

            for restaurants in snapshot.children.allObjects as![FIRDataSnapshot]
            {
                let restaurantObject = restaurants.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let restaurantName = restaurantObject?["name"]
                let restaurantPhone = restaurantObject?["phone"]

                let restaurant = RestaurantModel(name: name as! String?, phone: phone as! String?)

                self.restaurantList.append(restaurant)
            }
        }
        self.tableViewHongKong.reloadData()
    })
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return restaurantList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewControllerTableViewCell

    let restaurant: RestaurantModel

    restaurant = restaurantList[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurant.name

    return cell
}
}
```

This is the Table View Cell Class :

```
@IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
```

This is the Restaurant Model Class:

```
var name: String?
var phone: String?

init(name:String?, phone:String?) {
    self.name = name;
    self.phone = phone
}
```

As the image uploaded in another class, Restaurant.

```
var imageURL = ""
func addRestaurant()
{
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("restaurants")
    let key = ref?.childByAutoId().key
    let name = addName.text
    let phone = addPhone.text
    ref?.child(key!).setValue(["name": name, "phone": phone, "image": imageURL]) 
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    addImage.image = image
    var data = Data()
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

    let uniqueName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("restaurantImage").child("\(uniqueName)")
    imageRef.put(data, metadata: nil).observe(.success){(snapshot) in
        self.imageURL = (snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For more detail, may visit [Firebase Database Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44327131/8102507)

Thank you very much ! ^.^